# In my ASP.NET MVC app how can I determine if any property in my domain Model has changed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on the MVC prototype of a very large and complex ASP.NET 2.0 Webforms based business product suite for an organization. One of the capabilities inbuilt into the existing app is that it only hits the database to store a result set if the user made any changes at all on the Webforms UI. The web app has a complete layer built in to track this "if changed by user" thing.

I was wondering if within ASP.NET MVC there is a provision/functionality to determine what property was changed by the user on the view? The idea is simple, user sees a view, probably makes some changes and hits "Save". The controller that accepts the post needs to figure out if the state of the model was changed by the user or not and save it only if the state was changed.

Any thoughts?

PS: I am tagging this as mvc-2 and mvc-3 as it is a prototype. I am currently learning/developing this in MVC 2 but will quickly move to MVC 3 if that suits our needs better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if within ASP.NET MVC there is a provision/functionality to determine what property was changed by the user on the view?

No, there is nothing to do this in MVC. WebForms does this by including the original values of fields in the view state, but in embracing the statelessness of HTTP at its core MVC doesn't do this.

If your (view) model types are regular enough you might be able to construct scaffolding to do this (and the more types you have the more benefit to do this). I've prototyped something on these lines where each view model type determines if there have been changes when updating the model type before any update to the database (and thus bypasses the update).

Comment: Actually we don't use the ASP.NET's viewstate/post data collections to track this. We have custom controls for pretty much everything (textbox, combos etc) which track their own state. The form simply loops through the controls to figure out if anything was changed. I am going to look for scaffolding's details but a generic high level overview will be welcome :)

Comment: @Nikhil: And where do those control's store the original value?

Comment: We have a client side global framework which adds a changedValue class to each control the user changes. The controls have an IsDirty property which is set (differently for each control) depending on whether the control ended up with this class or not. True a few controls track changes in Viewstate too but most of them use the class route.

Comment: @Nikhil: Sorry, I should have been clearer--your controls are tracking their own state. ASP.NET MVC doesn't do this (the details of the mechanism don't matter). Therefore you need to completely rethink your approach. Doing "MVC with WebForms controls" is just going to lead to all the disadvantages of both approaches and the advantages of neither.

Comment: You are very right Richard. That is why I was trying to think of Models that are capable of tracking their state. In the world of HTTP it is a stupid thought and I know that! But with the point of view of business, a model that represents say a "Contract" represents an actual legal entity irrespective of whether it is served over HTTP or TCP/IP or on paper.

Comment: By the way I think I do have a solution to this problem which will leverage MVVM or view models. Details are a bit sketchy and it will tkae me a while to implement it. But unless something better comes along I will update this question with whatever option I chose.

Comment: @Nikhil: I would expect that the action method would get the original from the repository and then do the compare. The repository will hit the database or its caching layer (latter added if needed). Any holding on to state within the server needs to be done very carefully to avoid issues in the future (eg. multiple servers, app pool restarts, ...).

Comment: I am closing this question as it is no longer relevant to my project. However for your kind interest I am accepting your answer. it was quite close to my approach anyways!