# ASP.NET MVC, finding if model has changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I use the modelstate in ASP.NET MVC to see if the user has made changes or not?

For example:

A form gets loaded and the user has the ability to make changes on the form.
After making changes, users clicks apply or cancel button.

Clicking the button brings control back to my controller where I do validation, then commit to database.

What if the user clicks the apply button without making changes?  I want the controller to be able to detect that nothing was altered by the user and send the appropriate message.

Is there a way to detect this using modelstate?  Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your data layer (EF?) can probably do that for you.

Comment: duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934612/in-my-asp-net-mvc-app-how-can-i-determine-if-any-property-in-my-domain-model-has

Answer (score 4):

We use [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to take our domain entities and map them to view models.  Something like this:

```
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<DomainEntityClass, ViewModelClass>(entity);
```

Then, on post back of the view/page, we can test if they are different by loading the entity again and comparing it to the mapped view model:

```
var entity = Repository.Get<DomainEntityClass>(id);
var mappedEntity = Mapper.Map<DomainEntityClass, ViewModelClass>(entity);

// code to compare mappedEntity to incoming viewmodel
//
// or build an equality comparer to test them
```

The idea is that if the mapping configuration hasn't changed, the Mapper.Map call (given the same entity) should return matching view model objects if nothing has changed.

For help building equality comparers, check here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx

Comment: +1 from me. I had a similar response half written when you posted this.